# Getting best n solutions for ILP

Tags: linear-programming, solver

I'd like to use an ILP solver (e.g. `lp_solve`) to find the solution for an optimization problem.

The challenge is that some constraints are too complex to be formalized as linear statements, but may be validated using a simulation framework.

So I'd need to run the solver, check the solution against my complex constraints, and in case they are not satisfied, continue with the *second-best* solution etc.

**Is there a solver that does not only provide the optimal solution, but the *best n* solutions regarding the give objective function?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

1. Either the solver supports it through a solution pool,
2. or you have to build this solution pool yourself through the callback functions provided by the API of the solver.

In the latter case, the corresponding callback function is called whenever a new, better solution is found than the best known solution up to that point. The second option is supported by all the notable solvers I know of.

More on this topic:

- [K Best Solutions](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/k-best-solutions.html)
- [K Best Solutions in AMPL/CPLEX](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/k-best-solutions-in-amplcplex.html)

Comment: Thanks for this hint! The problem is that CPLEX is commercial, and I cannot find any other solver with such a callback (or solution pool)...

Comment: @lynix All solvers I know of have such a callback. Which solver are you using?

Comment: My favorite would be `lpsolve`, but [this](http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/Top-ranked-solutions-tp3153p3157.html) claims that it is not possible to get the best n solutions because of branch cutting.

Comment: @lynix OK, please give me some time, I will try to find the necessary functions. I haven't used the `lp_solve` API so I cannot tell you more about that particular solve.